# How to troubleshoot SSIS call to WCF

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, wcf, ssis

I have found many posts about this error, but so far have had no luck correcting mine.

We have a WCF we call using NetTcpBinding.  I have it set up from a SSIS package - Script Transformation to call the WCF.

I am able to run the SSIS package from my local Visual Studio and it works.  But I deploy it to the SSISDB, and run it, and it fails.  During my troubleshooting, I was commenting out the body, which is why the RunForecastViaWCFService is commented out.  As soon as I added the client.Open() / client.Close(), I started getting the errors.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The coding in the script transformation is:

```
private IClientChannel CreateClient()
{
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(this.Variables.ServiceURL);
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
    binding.ListenBacklog = 10;
    binding.MaxConnections = 10;

    var factory = new ChannelFactory<Infinity.ManufacturingPlanning.Service.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IForecastService>(binding, endpointAddress);
    var serviceChannel = factory.CreateChannel();
    IClientChannel clientChannel = serviceChannel as IClientChannel;

    return clientChannel;
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    try
    {
        var client = CreateClient();
        client.Open();

        var RunForecast = new Infinity.ManufacturingPlanning.Service.Contracts.ServiceModels.CreateForecastServiceModel
        {
            SellingDaysYear = Row.SellingDaysYear,
            SellingDaysPeriod = Row.SellingDaysPeriod,
            OperationsItemCategoryId = Guid.Parse(Row.OperationsItemCategoryId),
            OperationsItemSubCategoryId = Guid.Parse(Row.OperationsItemSubCategoryId),
        };

        //((Infinity.ManufacturingPlanning.Service.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IForecastService)client).RunForecastViaWCFService(RunForecast);
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have added many of the binding options just trying some of the suggestions I have been seeing in other SO posts.

The error is as follows:

```
Run WCF For Long Running Processes:Error:
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The
socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an
error processing your message or a receive timeout being
exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network
resource issue. Local socket timeout was
'00:09:59.9580000'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The write
operation failed, see inner exception. --->
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The
socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an
error processing your message or a receive timeout being
exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network
resource issue. Local socket timeout was
'00:09:59.9580000'. --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing
connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32
offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write
(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate,
TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write
(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate,
TimeSpan timeout)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write
Now(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan
timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
```

**Edits: Additional information after original post:**

In the end we found out it would work by running it from a SQL Server agent job, just not manually from executing under the Integration Services catalog.  (I normally make sure a package can work on it's own before creating a job to run it.  But I was desperately just trying random things.  I was surprised it worked.)  But I am still seeking to understand what/how the differences happen.  I could tell by the Caller on the execution report, this was ran by the gmsa account we have set up to run the Sql Agent Jobs.

But what really confused me was the following.
From my local laptop, using SSMS logged in as a user with sysadmin rights, using Execute under Integration Services Catalogs, it would fail.

Using VNC into the Server box, using SSMS logged in as the same user with sysadmin rights, using Execute under Integration Services Catalogs, it would pass.

Both of the above would work if the job was executed.  We have read mixed reviews as to whether SSMS should even be installed on the server itself.  So we really want to understand what rights/permissions etc affected our testing for better knowledge.

Comment: Did you see this in your error logs? System.IO.IOException: The write
operation failed. This could permissions. You may also want to check that the service you are calling is active.

Comment: The service is active.  For each change I make, I make sure it runs in Visual Studio first.  Then I deploy it to the SSISDB and run from there.  It works from VS, just not the SSIS.

Comment: Does your account that runs the ssis package have access to the server and wcf service?